# Running java Program on Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to run an applet program with some Hadoop file operations. I am using Eclipse Europa and it is working finer when I run the program on the Hadoop Server (option provided by Eclipse). But now I need to make the program as Jar and run it through cmd prompt on Hadoop Server.
Though I tried using "Hadoop jar Myjar.jar" command but it is not working.
Can somebody help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hadoop jar command runs a program contained in a JAR file. If you have already bundled your MapReduce code in a JAR file, you can execute it by using the following command:

```
Usage: `hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...`
```

Example:

```
`hadoop jar /home/825341/workspace/YourMapReduceJob.jar com.yourapp.MainClass mapreduce-input-directory-path mapreduce-output-directory-path arguments-to-your-driver-class-if-any`
```

I assumes that all the required libraries are available in your class path.

Comment: i am getting no output.Nither the JFrame nor any error. The cursor is just blinking on the cygwin window :(